# Updating a column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5), nrow=5))
```

To that i add a discrete variable

```
df$discrete <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
```

And i put on some meaningful colnames:

```
colnames (df) <- c("start", "discrete")
```

Now i want to create a new variable that is the first variable + 10 - but only if my discrete variable has the value 1

```
df$new_var <- as.numeric(10)

df$new_var[df$discrete == 1]  <- df$start + 10
```

And i get an error: Warning message: In df$new_var[df$discrete == 1] <- df$start + 10 : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

and my tables has not updated as expected. Whats going on?

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5), nrow=5))
df$discrete <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
colnames (df) <- c("start", "discrete")
df$new_var <- as.numeric(10)
df$new_var[df$discrete == 1]  <- df$start + 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a subset of a dataframe column (`df$new_var[df$discrete == 1]`) the data in an *entire* dataframe column (altered a bit): `df$start + 10`

Try this instead, which subsets both sides.

```
df$new_var[df$discrete == 1]  <- df$start[df$discrete == 1] + 10
```